# Inconsistent accessibility error C#

Tags: c#

Trying to work on a project but keep getting this error.

> Error  1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'GICT_Project.IObjects' is less accessible than method 'GICT_Project.DatabaseService.Insert(GICT_Project.IObjects)'  E:\GICT_Project\GICT_Project\DatabaseService.cs 86  28  GICT_Project

Don't know whats wrong. Have tried to change stuff to public but no dice.

Here's the problematic code:

```
public static void Insert(IObjects classType) //insert tool data
{
    string query = "";
    string type = (classType.GetType()).ToString();
    switch (type) {
        case "Tools":
            query = "INSERT INTO group2.Tools (ToolID, ToolName, Quantity) VALUES(" + classType.GetSqlInfo() + ")";
            break;
        case "Service":
            query = "INSERT INTO group2.Services (ServiceID, ServName, ToolID) VALUES(" + classType.GetSqlInfo() + ")";
            break;
        case "Location":
            query = "INSERT INTO group2.Location (LocationID, Location, Features) VALUES(" + classType.GetSqlInfo() + ")";
            break;
        case "Appointments":
            query = "INSERT INTO group2.Appointments (AppointmentID, CustomerID, ServiceID, LocationID, EmployeeID) VALUES(" + classType.GetSqlInfo() + ")";
            break;
        case "Employee":
            query = "INSERT INTO group2.Employee (EmployeeID, EmpName, EmpBirthday, EmpAddress, LocationID) VALUES(" + classType.GetSqlInfo() + ")";
            break;
        case "Customer":
            query = "INSERT INTO group2.Customer (CustomerID, CusName, CusBirthday, CusAddress) VALUES(" + classType.GetSqlInfo() + ")";
            break;
        case "Skills":
            query = "INSERT INTO group2.Skills (SkillID, SkillName) VALUES(" + classType.GetSqlInfo() + ")";
            break;
            //many to many tables need to create rows on connecting tables when initialised
    }
    InsertQuery(query);
}
```

And this is separate class:

```
interface IObjects
{
    string GetSqlInfo();
    int GetId();
    void InsertData();
}
```

Comment: If you don't tell the compiler what accessibility to give your class/interface/whatever, it will default to `internal`. So your interface is internal while your class is public.

Comment: Sure it isn't internal (for classes and interfaces of course)? @DavidG

Comment: @PatrickHofman Er, you are right! Either way this is a dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your interface public since the method that exposes it is public. If you don't do that, the consumer of that method doesn't know the actual type of the receiving parameter.

The solution would be to add the `public` keyword before `interface`:

```
public interface IObjects
{
    string GetSqlInfo();
    int GetId();
    void InsertData();
}
```

Or make the method not `public`, but `internal`, the default accessibility of classes and interfaces.

```
internal static void Insert(IObjects classType) //insert tool data
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your interface public.

```
public interface IObjects
{
    string GetSqlInfo();
    int GetId();
    void InsertData();
}
```

Or make `Insert` method internal compiler is reporting this error because you are exposing `IObjects` interface which is internal to the public method so in a way it becomes accessible to the outside dlls through `Insert` method.

Comment: Right. I think it worked. Just get a whole bunch of other errors, but these are a whole another story. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the interface to be

```
public interface IObjects
```